# Concrete example of an admissible A* heuristic compared to Djisktra

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

As I understand it, A* is a general form of Djikstra where the selection of the next node to visit can be based on something other than the actual distance. For example, with Djikstra, you'd use a priority queue ordered ascending by distance and shift off the head of the queue to decide where to visit next. But with A*, the order of the priority queue can be based off of the actual distance and/or another factor (the heuristic). The heuristic is considered admissible if the value it returns is guaranteed to be equal to or less than the actual distance. In other words, Djikstra is a form of A* where the heuristic always returns the actual distance.

So, what is a concrete example of an admissible A* heuristic?

It seems like writing a heuristic function that always returns an equal to or lesser value than the actual distance would require some magical insight about the graph obtained if I already knew the shortest distances.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) has an example. Intuitively, when creating an admissible heuristic, you find the lowest possible estimate on the distance. E.g. for a distance on a plane when you have obstacles, the actual distance would require you to get around these obstacles, while for an admissible heuristic you can assume that there are no obstacles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, Djikstra is a form of A* where the heuristic always returns the actual distance.

This is wrong.  Dijkstra's is a form of A* where the heuristic *is always 0*.

Dijkstra's algorithm is essentially the weighted-graph version of a breadth-first search.  It simply spreads out from the start node in all directions until it researches the end node.  It could spend a lot of time searching paths that are going in the complete opposite direction of the end, because it doesn't know anything about the global properties of the graph.

That's where the heuristic comes in.  Since we know the approximate direction of the end, we can prioritize searches that move in that direction.  In a 2D graph, for example, this would mean prioritizing searches that are closer to the end from a bird's-eye view.

The heuristic is *added* to the total distance so far to determine which nodes to consider next.  If the heuristic is 0, then we're only using the distances known so far, meaning we don't prioritize any direction and we get Dijkstra's algorithm again.  However, if it's non-zero, we do prioritize certain directions, which hopefully leads to us reaching the end sooner.

Note that the heuristic is just an estimate, *not* the actual distance to the end.  In fact, it's more than an estimate - it's a lower-bound to the actual distance *(that's what "admissible" means)*.  In our 2D example, our heuristic is the bird's-eye view straight-line, which is the shortest possible path between two points.  Adding obstacles will never decrease this path length, only increase it.

Comment: i now see how we can come up with a lower bound to the actual distance (eg, disregard obstacles), but i cant think of any other ways in which we might come up with an admissible heuristic. for example, is there some popular heuristic that doesnt just boil down to ignoring obstacles or measuring a line between the two points?

Comment: @tau One famous example: you can solve the "15 puzzle" using A\*, with a heuristic of how many pieces are out of place (and optionally, by how far)